# Number of Ways to Arrange Letters with Restriction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have 2 types of letters - 3 As and 4 Bs. I want to know how many ways I can arrange a 7 character "word" where no two As may be adjacent.

My idea was find the number of total possible arrangements and then subtract how many ways two As are adjacent. I know there are a total of $\frac{7!}{3!4!} = 35$ ways to arrange them in general, but I'm not sure how I would find the number of ways that two As are adjacent.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The numbers are so small here, it should be easy to do by hand.  You have $\_ABABA\_$  and each of the other two $B's$ can either go into the empty slots at the end or into the gaps between consecutive $A's$.  Alternately, think of your word as $B^{n_1}AB^{n_2}AB^{n_3}AB^{n_4}$ where $n_2,n_3≥1$ and $n_1,n_4≥0$ and, of course $\sum n_i=4$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is a simplified version of a much larger problem I want to tackle. I want to know the math behind it, not just counting it out.

Comment: So use the second approach I sketched and look up [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: @Saul5813 If that is the case, you need to include that relevant context in your question, since it affects how people approach answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $k$ $A's$ and $n$ B's

The $A's$ can be placed one each anywhere in the $n+1$ interstices of $B's$ including ends.

So you can place the $A's$ in $\binom{n+1}{k}$ ways

Can you work out what relationship between the # of $A's$ and $B's$ is necessary to be able to place the $A's$ so that no two are adjacent ?